# .NET 5 MVC - Publish project from linux using dotnet CLI with .publishsettings file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, publishing

I've completed my .net 5 mvc app, and I'd like to put it on "webio.pl" shared hosting. I know how to do it on windows through visual studio, but here on linux, I got only dotnet cli. I've downloaded .publishsettings file from server admin panel, but dunno how to actually use "dotnet publish" command proper. I know it might be a stupid question, but any help appreciated. File contains  tag, with  tag with things like userName, msdeploySite, etc. in attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this might not be possible?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#publish-to-an-msdeploy-endpoint-from-the-command-line says:

> The dotnet msbuild command is a cross-platform command and can compile ASP.NET Core apps on macOS and Linux. However, MSBuild on macOS and Linux isn't capable of deploying an app to Azure or other MSDeploy endpoints.

But it also says that if it did work, the command would look like this:

```
dotnet msbuild "AzureWebApp.csproj"
    /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
    /p:PublishProfile="AzureWebApp - Web Deploy" 
    /p:Username="$AzureWebApp" 
    /p:Password=".........."
```

But you would have to figure out the property names and values from the `.publishsettings` xml file yourself.